# D3 graph tooltip should show nearest point on hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have made a graph using D3 but the problem is that I want its tooltip to appear on the graph as per nearest mouse point over in the graph. I have also seen one example on StackOverflow here on this link - [D3: Get nearest value from ordinal axis on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211819/d3-get-nearest-value-from-ordinal-axis-on-mouseover). Which is doing the exact what I want but when I implemented the same code on my graph then it is not working. Please take a look at my code and suggest me changes.

IMPORTANT!: I also want when someone double click on the graph then tooltip x'axis & y'axis coordinated stay there. Your valuable time is highly appreciated. Please Help!!!

```html
<div id='chartdiv'></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>
function getData(){ 
data1 = [{x:1,y:15},{x:2,y:26},{x:3,y:17},{x:4,y:21},];
return data1};

function drawChart(data) {
var coreheight = 720
var corewidth = 1280
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 60}
, width = corewidth - margin.left - margin.right
, height = coreheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }),
xRange = xExtent[1] - xExtent[0],
yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; }).reverse(),
yRange = yExtent[1] - yExtent[0];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([50, width]).domain([xExtent[0] - (xRange * .05), xExtent[1] + (xRange * .05)]);;
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, height]).domain([yExtent[0] - (yRange * .1), yExtent[1] + (yRange * .05)]);;

var line = d3.line()
 .x(function(d, x) { return xScale(d.x); })
 .y(function(d, y) { return yScale(d.y); })
 .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

d3.select('#chartdiv')
 .append('svg')
 .attr('class','graph')
 .style('background-color','#fff')
 .attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+ corewidth +" "+ coreheight +"");

var svg = d3.select(".graph")
 .append("g")
 .attr("class", "dchart")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(7))
 .attr("transform", "translate(50, 0)")
 .attr('font-size','25px');

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(7))
 .attr('font-size','25px');

svg.append("path")
 .datum(data)
 .attr("class", "line")
 .attr("d", line);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("class", "dot")
 .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.x) })
 .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
 .attr("r", 8)
 .on("mouseover", mousehover)
 .on("mouseout", mousehoverout) 

function mousehover(d) { 
   svg.append("text")
    .attr('class','annot')
    .attr('x', xScale(d.x) - 20)
    .attr('y', yScale(d.y) - 23)
    .text(d.x+','+d.y)
    .style('font-size','30px')
   svg.append('line')
    .attr('class','annot')
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr('stroke-width','3')
    .attr("x1", xScale(d.x))
   .attr("y1", yScale(d.y))
    .attr("x2", xScale(d.x))
    .attr("y2", height);
    }

function mousehoverout() {  
    d3.selectAll('.annot').remove()
  }

}drawChart(getData());
</script>

<style>
.line {fill: none;stroke: darkblue;stroke-width: 3}
.dot {fill: darkblue;stroke-width:0}
</style>
```

Comment: When you say "I also want when someone double click on the graph then tooltip x'axis & y'axis coordinated stay there" what should happen when the mouse moves? Do you want all the tooltips to remain displayed?

Comment: For example, if the users has double clicked on the chart and the first data point has its tooltip, then the user moves closer to the second data point, what should happen?

Comment: Sir, Please take a look here, I have created a W3school example that what should happen here - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFNFAMDT5HS5. In this example when you double click on circle then it appends a text with coordinated and also a line. Also when you drag the text then line also go with it.

Comment: I have made that but problem is that tooltip only appears exactly on the circle but I want when someone mouse hover on graph then it shows the nearest tooltip; and also when someone double click on graph then it should append draggable text with coordinates and a line like in the w3school example I have given. Please help sir if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track where the mouse is on the chart, you're currently only checking if the mouse is hovering on a dot.

I've added a couple of event handlers to the entire chart:

```js
 .on("mousemove", mousemove)
 .on("mouseout", mousehoverout);
```

One you have already implemented, `mousehoverout`, and the other, `mousemove`, which tracks where the mouse is relative to the points.

```js
var lastIndex = -1;

function mousemove()
{
  let x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
  let closest = data.reduce((best, value, i) => 
    {
      let absx = Math.abs(xScale(value.x) - x) 
      if(absx < best.value) 
      {
        return {index: i, value:absx};
      }
      else
      {
        return best;
      }
    }, {index:0, value:Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER});

  if(lastIndex != closest.index)
  {
    d3.selectAll('.annot').remove();
    lastIndex = closest.index;
  }
  mousehover(data[closest.index]);
}
```

Then to add the double click functionality, you can do as you have shown in the w3schools link, but add the handler to the chart:

```
.on('dblclick', function(){/* your code in here */});
```

```js
function getData(){ 
data1 = [{x:1,y:15},{x:2,y:26},{x:3,y:17},{x:4,y:21},];
return data1};

function drawChart(data) {
var coreheight = 720
var corewidth = 1280
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 100, left: 60}
, width = corewidth - margin.left - margin.right
, height = coreheight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }),
xRange = xExtent[1] - xExtent[0],
yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; }).reverse(),
yRange = yExtent[1] - yExtent[0];

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([50, width]).domain([xExtent[0] - (xRange * .05), xExtent[1] + (xRange * .05)]);;
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, height]).domain([yExtent[0] - (yRange * .1), yExtent[1] + (yRange * .05)]);;

var line = d3.line()
 .x(function(d, x) { return xScale(d.x); })
 .y(function(d, y) { return yScale(d.y); })
 .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

d3.select('#chartdiv')
 .append('svg')
 .attr('class','graph')
 .style('background-color','#fff')
 .attr("viewBox", "0 0 "+ corewidth +" "+ coreheight +"")
 .on('dblclick', function(){if(lastIndex > -1) { createpeak(data[lastIndex]); } })
 .on("mousemove", mousemove)
 .on("mouseout", mousehoverout);

var svg = d3.select(".graph")
 .append("g")
 .attr("class", "dchart")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(7))
 .attr("transform", "translate(50, 0)")
 .attr('font-size','25px');

svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(7))
 .attr('font-size','25px');

svg.append("path")
 .datum(data)
 .attr("class", "line")
 .attr("d", line);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("class", "dot")
 .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d.x) })
 .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
 .attr("r", 8);

var lastIndex = -1;

function mousemove()
{
  let x = d3.mouse(this)[0];
  let closest = data.reduce((best, value, i) => 
    {
      let absx = Math.abs(xScale(value.x) - x) 
      if(absx < best.value) 
      {
        return {index: i, value:absx};
      }
      else
      {
        return best;
      }
    }, {index:0, value:Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER});
    
  d3.selectAll('.annot').remove();
  lastIndex = closest.index;
  mousehover(data[closest.index]);
}

function mousehover(d) { 
   svg.append("text")
    .attr('class','annot')
    .attr('x', xScale(d.x) - 20)
    .attr('y', yScale(d.y) - 23)
    .text(d.x+','+d.y)
    .style('font-size','30px')
   svg.append('line')
    .attr('class','annot')
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr('stroke-width','3')
    .attr("x1", xScale(d.x))
    .attr("y1", yScale(d.y))
    .attr("x2", xScale(d.x))
    .attr("y2", height);
    }

var i = 1;
var m = 1;
function createpeak(d) {
console.log('redacted');
         }

function dragstarted(d,e){
d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
var current = d3.select(this);
deltaX = current.attr("x") - d3.event.x;
deltaY = current.attr("y") - d3.event.y;
}
    
function dragged(d,e){
d3.select(this).attr("x",d3.event.x + deltaX)
d3.select(this).attr("y",d3.event.y + deltaY)
for (var i=1; i <= 100; i++){
d3.select('.line'+i).attr("x2", function (d) {
return d3.select('.peak'+i).attr("x") - deltaX
});
d3.select('.line'+i).attr("y2", function (d) {
return d3.select('.peak'+i).attr("y") - deltaY
})}}

function dragended(d,e){}

function mousehoverout() {

        
  }

}drawChart(getData());
```

```css
.line {fill: none;stroke: darkblue;stroke-width: 3}
.dot {fill: darkblue;stroke-width:0}
```

```html
<div id='chartdiv'></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your response sir, but when I double click and simply hover on graph it automatically create peaks on hovering only. Please if you can adjust if it create peak only on double click not even on hovering after double click. Also the drag function not working in this. Your time is really appreciated sir thank you very much for your humble response.

Comment: I have updated my code to include your code. It should work now

Comment: Thank You very much for your help sir, There is little problem in this that when I hover on exactly the circle or on tooltip line then the tooltip disappear. Can you please also solve this problem.

Comment: Also when I added more data points in the graph tooltip disappears a lot because when mouse is over actual data point then tooltip disappear. Also the tooltip is not exactly on mouse position it is like 50 to 70 px on right hand side. I also notice when I inspect on hovering it appends many tooltip texts and lines instead of appending just one text & one line (that might be the reason of disappearing tooltip). Thanks a lot you in advance.

Comment: even the tooltip is disappearing when hover over it text. I think there are 2 tooltips because on hover over the tooltip text then previous tooltip also shows up which is having lightly font than this. Even on inspect there are many tooltip appears.

Comment: @Instanano yes, that's what your code does. I've stopped the marker disappearing when you hover over the label for it.

Comment: Can you please make it so that it only creates one tooltip text and line because tooltip is looking meshy as it is creating many text and lines over and over again. Also when mouse is move out of the graph, tooltip still left shown there on the graph it should also be removed after mouse left the graph. Sorry sir Im bothering you so much but its purely an education project, and you are helping in this very much, thank you so much for your kind support.

Comment: I have made it so the tooltips clear each time before drawing the correct one. I can't remove the tooltip from the chart when the mouse goes out of the chart, because hovering over the label is the same as going out of the chart.

Comment: I have removed it.